# Automatically switch to the speaking user in Google+ Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

In Google+ Hangouts, I see that by default the user who is speaking gets his/her picture in the main viewing pane, but clicking on another user's picture in the lower pane puts him/her in the main viewing pane. But how do I restore automatic control?

In other words, after having clicked one of the users, how can I revert to having the currently-speaking user be automatically loaded into the main viewing pane?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply click the user you prioritised again (they should have a blue outline around them) and Google+ Hangouts will resume automatically prioritising the user speaking loudest.

[image]

Comment: That is both surprising and obvious